# How to captured the `data model` using programming approach in a "model file" such as `JSON` and `XML`?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, relational-database, database-schema

Is there any `java programming approach` using that I can captured the `data model` in a "model file" such as `JSON` and `XML`?

The following is a short example of how the model could be stored in the model file.

[image]

As illustrated, the columns and the Primary Keys are defined for each table as well as the RI in the form of P-FK or C-FK – primary or the child table for the FK.

Edited:

I looking for any `3rd party tool` written in `java` similar like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/documentation/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html).

This looks pretty cool because Propel uses an abstract XML schema file to represent databases (the schema). Propel builds the SQL specific to a database based on this schema and provides a way to reverse-engineer the generic schema file based on database metadata.

Comment: Please, can you explain a little more detailed, what your exact problem is? As far as I understand, you have a relational database schema with two tables. And you want to write a Java tool to connect to your database and extract the databse's metadata and create a XML or JSON file containing this metadata? Is this what you want?

Comment: I looking for any 3rd party tool written in java similar like Propel. http://propelorm.org/documentation/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html

This looks pretty cool because Propel uses an abstract XML schema file to represent databases (the schema). Propel builds the SQL specific to a database based on this schema and provides a way to reverse-engineer the generic schema file based on database metadata.